# map matrix into specific vector with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I have matrix similar to this:

```
1 0 0
1 0 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 0 3
0 0 3
```

(Non-zero numbers denote parts that I'm interested in. Actual number inside matrix could be random.)

And I need to produce vector like this:

```
[ 1 1 2 2 3 3 ].T
```

I can do this with loop:

```
result = np.zeros([rows])
for y in range(rows):
    x = y // (rows // cols)  # pick index of corresponded column
    result[y] = mat[y][x]
```

But I can't figure out how to do this in vector form.

Comment: how about `mat[mat != 0]`?

Comment: > But instead of 0 there are some garbage

Comment: numbers are just marks, its should help you to see what parts of matrix I want to extract

Comment: "Instead of 0 there are some garbage" what is this supposed to mean? Being 0 makes a huge difference. You want simply `x.sum(axis=1)` the sum of your rows in your example...

Comment: I just wanted to highlight segments that I interested in. You can think of numbers inside matrix as some random value.

Comment: Do you just need single digit integers from the matrix? By garbage do you mean other big numbers?

Comment: By garbage I meant any number. I updated question.

Comment: So if the first row of your provided matrix is `1 7 2` instead of `1 0 0`, shall we consider `7` and `2` as garbage? Plz clarify your definition of garbage. Even 1,2,3 can be called 'Any number`. Do you mean to say you just want `1` `2` and `3` in the output and everything else is considered garbage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you want.

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 3],
    [0, 0, 3]
])

rows, cols = m.shape
# axis1 indices
y = np.arange(rows)
# axis2 indices
x = y // (rows // cols)

result = m[y,x]

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[1 1 2 2 3 3]
```